# Sugarhill Gang - Apache (Jump on it) - real title?

Tags: song-title, hip-hop

That's the song that they do street dance to in some dancing school, so i was curious as it has bits from Shadows - Apache. I called it Apache (Jump on it) when I found it on YouTube but the children insist it's only called Jump on it.

Google thinks it's called Apache (Jump on it).
According to Wikipedia's article about Sugarhill Gang it's called Apache and was released as a single. But it mentions the album called Jump on it and according to Discogs there's a song on that album called Jump on it. But otherwise searching for the song comes up with Apache (Jump on it).

Maybe Sugarhill Gang "originally" called that song Apache but much later that song (and the album on which or was re-released) was called Jump on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original song "Apache" was an instrumental, inspired by the film of the same title.  A cover version by the Incredible Bongo Band became part of the foundational sound of hip hop after being frequently and heavily sampled by early hip-hop artists.

The Sugarhill Gang actually released two versions of the song.  Confusingly, the one called "Apache" is often referred to as "Jump on it" because the Sugarhill Gang added that lyric as a oft-repeated, and catchy call-and-response style refrain, while the one actually titled "Jump on it!" doesn't actually include that lyric.

It's most likely that the song the kids mean is "Apache," since "Jump on it" is a widely used (if unofficial) alternate title for it.  The actual "Jump on it!" is much less well known.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_(instrumental)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was partly right about the re-release except it was changed. I didn't expect that a Wikipedia article about the song would tell so much. In particular the confusing detail about 2 versions. Next time I watch their performance I'll listen to find out which one they're playing. Also I didn't know that The Shadows' version wasn't (quite) the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Incredible Bongo Band’s song “Apache” was actually a cover of an original instrumental surf rock song by The Ventures in the mid 1960’s. I knew that sample sounded familiar so I went into my dad’s old record collection and found the song in that album.